# Adjusting headline in article

Tags: header-footer, pagestyle

i have the following problem when I am adjusting my header:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, german]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm,}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\ohead{\headmark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark{section}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=40mm,right=30mm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm}

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\newpage

\section{BBBTest}
\end{document}
```

I tried `fancyhdr`, `plain` and header all ready and it doesnt work for me. It puts the headers above each other for example. Here I have the problem that it puts the header twice at the left and the right hand side.

What I want is: the page number at the bottom in the middle of the page and a header of the section or subsection at the top left-hand side with a line below the header.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I didnt get any error messages, but i dont want a line at the bottom. I just want the page number down in the middle and a header at the top.

Comment: Please see my added answer!

Answer (score 1):

Well, with class `article` I would prefer to use package `fancyhdr`. Package `scrpage2` is outdated, use package `scrlayer-scrpage` instead! Because you are writing in german have you considered to use class `scrartcl` instead? And `scrlayer-scrpage` is designed to work optimal with any KOMA-Script class, for example `scrartcl` ...

Nevertheless, here is the solution for class `article` and `scrlayer-scrpage`:

You need to add option `headsepline` to get the wanted line under the header and you need to add command `\clearscrheadfoot` to get rid of all pre-definition the package `scrlayer-scrpage` usualy did ...

Please see the following MWE (with package `blindtext` to add some dummy text into the document):

```
\documentclass[%
  11pt, 
  a4paper,
  ngerman
]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=40mm,right=30mm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[%
  headsepline, % <======================================================
]{scrlayer-scrpage} % <=================================================
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot % <========================== clear all pre-definitions
\ohead{\headmark}
\cfoot{\pagemark}
\automark{section}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A}
\blindtext
\newpage

\section{BBBTest}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Please also note that I deleted all not needed packages for this issue! Now you get the following result:

[image: resulting pages]

Have you noticed the warning you should have got by compiling my MWE? It is:

> ```
> Package scrlayer-scrpage Warning: \headheight to low.
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                At least 13.59999pt needed,
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                but only 12.0pt found.
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                I'll enlarge \headheight, for further
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                processing, but you should do this yourself,
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                e.g., setting geometry's option
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                `head=13.59999pt'.
> (scrlayer-scrpage)                I'll also decrease \topmargin on input line 30.
> ```

So you should add the option `head=13.6pt` for `geometry`:

```
\geometry{%
  a4paper,left=40mm,right=30mm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, 
  head=13.6pt % <=======================================================
}
```

With the new MWE you can compile without error message or warning:

```
\documentclass[%
  11pt, 
  a4paper,
  ngerman
]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
  a4paper,left=40mm,right=30mm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, 
  head=13.6pt % <=======================================================
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[%
  headsepline, % <======================================================
]{scrlayer-scrpage} % <=================================================
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot % <========================== clear all pre-definitions
\ohead{\headmark}
\cfoot{\pagemark}
\automark{section}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A}
\blindtext
\newpage

\section{BBBTest}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]